# Binding of Isaac achievements and Steam in-game not working

Tags: steam, achievements, the-binding-of-isaac

I can't get achievements in this game, also the Steam In-game function doesn't work.
May this problem related to the fact that the game is in Flash? Anyone has the same problem?

Comment: Is this in Windows or OSX? Because currently the game's achievements will not work in OSX (and support is not planned at this time).

Comment: Do you mean that you can't get achievements at all, or that they simply don't pop up, as per agent86's answer?

Comment: This in Windows. The achievements simply don't pop-up, so in my profile I have 0 achievements, when actually I have the most of them. Sorry for not being specificy in the question above.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Crag. Guess it just sucks to be a mac user, buying games that are partially supported and they don't even think it's worth it to tell you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Windows, the FlashAchievements.exe that ships with the game is broken for many people. I've contacted Edmund with information about a fix, not sure when that's going out but he says he's working on it after this update goes out, in the meantime the fix on this page works:

http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2216833

You want the 1.5 version, the second link to a zip on that page. This is for windows, on the Mac there's nothing at present.

Comment: Weird, I've never had a problem with the achievements (on Windows).

Comment: I was having the same problem, and the file on that link fixed it for me.

Comment: lunboks, just edited the answer to say broken for many people instead of just broken.

Comment: The fix worked well, thanks! Is there a fix for the in-game issue? (I checked: the option "in-game" is activated in the proprieties of the game).

Comment: you can't being up the overlay because it's a flash game. I don't think there's any way around that.

Comment: In Machinarium and Super Meat Boy the in-game function works fine. So I think it isn't only a Flash problem.

Comment: Super Meat Boy isn't flash.

Comment: Machinarium is Flash, you're right. Didn't know that was possible, as other Flash games like Windosill don't work with overlay. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Oh, in fact I wasn't sure about Super Meat Boy; I also tried in TRAUMA (another game in Flash) and in-game works. Hope they fix it in tBoI.

Answer (score 2):

If you're paranoid like me and don't want to download things from the internet that you're not sure where they come from something that works for me is this:

I unlock some stuff and finish my run (steam has not registered any achievements). Shut the game off. Go into Isaac folder in the steam tree and remove FlashAchievements.exe. Go into Steam, verify integrity of files, Steam notices FlashAchievements.exe is missing and downloads it. Start the game up and get the achievements.

The annoying this is that this has to be done each time the game is started up, i.e. this works the time the game is started right after verifying and getting FlashAchievements.

That said; well done on fixing the issue InsidiousForce.

Answer (score 0):

When I was trying to get the Krampus achievement, I noticed this as well.  The achievement popped fine in Steam, but the overlay wasn't really working properly.  I wanted to take some screenshots for my answer, but I wasn't able to do that either.

[Some people](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2223332) were able to fix this by upgrading to the latest flash client, however.